# Deleted file gets moved to other library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have been asked by my supervisor to figure out a workflow that when someone (who obviously has permission) deletes a document from a document library it automatically gets moved to another document library (that hasn't been created yet) called 'Deleted Docs". Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: You can enable archiving policy for the library. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/10/03/applying-document-retention-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Workflow is the simple way . Refer the blog to follow step by step http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointArchiveDocs.htm

Comment: Thanks Nikhil looks exactly like what i want to accomplish

Comment: np , u can vote up pls .